# How to remove the square bracket from the python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

[image]I have created a pandas dataframe and have stored my information in the given frame as DF

when i print df
i get the output as

```
Number  changes                                       Id
300     ['Body Weight', 'Color']                     12345
400                                                  32145
500                                                  45698
600                                                  74125
700     Body Weight                                  96325
800     Body Weight                                   44444
900     ['band Voltage Rating', 'Body Weight']       963258
1000                                                 666666
```

In some places for column changes There are "[" and "]" . Please let me know how can I remove those brackets?

Comment: Maybe apply `str(changes).strip('[').strip(']')` to the changes column someway?

Comment: No , its not working.

Comment: Looks like some objects in the column are lists.

Comment: Yes. The format type is List for column "changes"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might help. Use `.apply` with `lambda`. I am using `isinstance` to check if type is list.

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"changes": [['Body Weight', 'Color'], ['band Voltage Rating', 'Body Weight'], "aaaaa"]})
print(df["changes"].apply(lambda x: ",".join(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x))
```

**Output:**

```
0                  Body Weight,Color
1    band Voltage Rating,Body Weight
2                              aaaaa
Name: changes, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you have a list of values in your data frame, hence the brackets. Here is how you can remove all brackets from you lists easily in a column. Here is how it would work on a sample dataframe. (The key is casting each line to a string before splitting it)

```
    import pandas as pd
    d = {'col1': [["dog","cat"],["apple","pear"]],'col2': [3,4]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    df['col1'] = pd.DataFrame([str(line).strip('[').strip(']') for line in df['col1']])
```

From my example you just need to replace the column name 'col1' with 'changes' and then replace 'df' with the name of your dataframe. You will notice that the quotes will still be shown in the final output. If you wish to remove these you can do the following instead:

```
    df['col1'] = pd.DataFrame([str(line).strip('[').strip(']').replace("'","") for line in df['col1']])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is totally normal. Column `changes` have `cells` of multiple values and so are of type `list` If a single column `cell` have multiple values, `dataframe` represents them as a list. This is very useful feature of `dataframe`  that you can access a particular `cell` information of `dataframe` in very structured way. You don't need to remove square brackets, it will go if you use correct way to print or use `list`. If you convert a `cell` of `dataframe` to string, then you need to `strip` brackets, otherwise it will not bother you if you use correct code to play with `list`